# Calling a df.loc function from separate module in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a function using .loc within a separate module that I want to be reusable in multiple programs.  Here is an example of the function:

```
def research_data_dictionary():

    df.loc[df.ProductName == 'Product1', "DescriptorName"] = 'CP AA'
    df.loc[df.ProductName == 'Product2', "DescriptorName"] = 'CP BBB'
```

When I import the function into another program as `research_data_dictionary()`, I get:

`NameError: global name 'df' is not defined`

I understand why I am getting this error (df not being defined within the function), but I am clueless on how to call the function since df is being defined within the program that I want to complete the df.locs.  Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: One option is to pass `df` as parameter to your function: `research_data_dictionary(df)`

Comment: @luis.parravicini - Thanks.  Forgot to mention that I tried that initially and did not get the error, but the df.loc did not execute.

Comment: What you mean by 'did not execute'? After declaring the parameter in the function definition, have you passed your dataframe as argument when calling it? Please update your question with the code you've tried.

Comment: @luis.parravicini -  Sure.  This is what it looks like in the function definition:

    def research_data_dictionary(df):

    df.loc[df.ProductName == 'ABC', "ProductName"] = 'CPE"

And here is what it looks like when I call the function:

research_data_dictionary(df)